# Never runs `if` , always `else`

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement

For some reason, my (basic) program always prints the text I reserved for my `else` statement.
I am a newb when it comes to Java, so if I am making an obvious mistake I apologize. I also searched high and low for an answer, but couldn't find one. Could you take a look at this:

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class tutorial_7 {

    private static Scanner x;

        public static void main(String args []) {
            x = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Apples, or oranges: ");
            String bog = x.next();

            if (bog == "Apples") {
                System.out.print(1);
            }
            if (bog == "Oranges") {
                System.out.print(2);
            }
            else {
                System.out.print(3);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why is the text reserved for my `if` statements never being output? Everything seems to be fine.

Regards,
JavaNoob

Comment: Use `.equals` to compare strings instead of `==`.

Comment: Thank you, Vulcan. And arshaiji, I suppose that would have solved my question had I found that post beforehand. Thank you for the reference, though.

Comment: You need to use equals method for that. Read this. http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/07/27/string-comparison-with-equals-and-assignment-operator/

Comment: If you want to use '==' itself you can rewrite it like: 
if(bog.intern() == "Apples") {}
Then it will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `==` to compare strings, it's for object identity.

Comparing strings should be done with the `equals()` method, such as:

```
if (bog.equals ("Oranges")) {
```

Comment: Perfect. I will accept this answer when I can (9 minutes, the timer says). It seems I am too used to C++ and Python.

Answer (score 1):

[How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java/513839#513839)

```
 if (bog.equals("Apples")){
    System.out.print(1);
  }
  if (bog.equals("Oranges")){
      System.out.print(2);
  }
  else{
    System.out.print(3);
  }
```